# Just a little confused on linux ownership

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 server and I just finished up configuring my forums, however I'm trying to install a new theme with for this software and think i have just about got it.

```
/var/www/html/styles# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 Jul  6 14:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 www-data www-data 4096 Jul  6 12:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data root     4096 Jul  6 14:07 SE_Gamer_Dark
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 Jul  6 11:28 prosilver`
```

Question: `drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data root     4096 Jul  6 14:07 SE_Gamer_Dark`

how do i change `root` in the above line? i thought this was file-permissions and needed a chown which i did : `chown www-data SE_Gamer_Dark`. This only however change the initial
 `drwxr-xr-x  6 root root     4096 Jul  6 14:07 SE_Gamer_Dark` **to the one you see,** 
`drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data root     4096 Jul  6 14:07 SE_Gamer_Dark`

As far as i know, the user "root" has the right to read and write this file, but i need www-data to be able to? I tried chmod aswell, but it didn't change the `root`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
chgrp www-data SE_Gamer_Dark
```

Second parameter is group

Comment: it tells me that 
`chgrp: cannot access 'SE_Gamer_DARK': No such file or directory` SE_Gamer_DARK is a folder that holds the theme fies. Is that considered a group? @maskacovnik

Comment: Are you in still in parent directory? maybe you havent rights to do it @WilliamMabry

Comment: according to `pwd` i am at `/var/www/html/styles` @maskacovnik which is where all of my forum files are(the folder that has the styles in them)

Comment: I see a problem, this is a "upper case" problem, your folder is caled Dark in lower case, not DARK in upper, I have rewrited it from your question, where you have both versions, answer edited @WilliamMabry

Comment: this fixed the error mentioned above and accomplished my initial question, however it did not fix what i was hoping it would :( thanks though! @maskacovnik

Answer (score 1):

You can change group only:

```
chgrp www-data SE_Gamer_DARK
```

Or group and user at the same time:

```
chown www-data root.SE_Gamer_DARK
```

In the example above `root` is the user and `SE_Gamer_DARK` is a group

You can also do it for entire subtree:

```
chown -R www-data root.SE_Gamer_DARK
```